# Create a custom event upon completion of ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a custom event listerner upon completion of a `$post` ajax call. Here is my code:

```
$.post( url, data, function(response) {
    //Fadeout the ajax loder image
    $('#ajax-image').fadeOut();

    //Insert the Response (HTML Format) in a hidden div
    $('#scpanels').html(response).fadeIn();

    // Create an event so that other scripts can interact
    $.response.trigger('MyCustomEvent');
});
```

And then, in other js files:

```
$( document ).on( 'MyCustomEvent', function() {

    //Do stuffs when that AJAX call finishes

});
```

This is not working at all. Sorry, I am new to jQuery and this perhaps beyond my current capabilities.

Thanks

Comment: May be you'll find what you are looking for here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is trigger it on the `document` and not on the `response`

like so:

```
$.post( url, data, function(response) {
    //Fadeout the ajax loder image
    $('#ajax-image').fadeOut();

    //Insert the Response (HTML Format) in a hidden div
    $('#scpanels').html(response).fadeIn();

    // Create an event so that other scripts can interact
    $(document).trigger('MyCustomEvent'); // only change here
});
```

Then it should work

**Update: Simple example without ajax.** I was just wondering how this works over multiple js files as I have never done that before and that is part of your question. So I just created a simple example maybe it helps you.

Create a `index.html` file in a directory with this content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="click-me">click-me</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="./script-1.js"></script>
    <script src="./script-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then create two js files in the same directory. One `script-1.js`

```
$('.click-me').on('click', function(){
    $(document).trigger('MyCustomEvent');
});
```

and the other one `script-2.js`

```
$( document ).on('MyCustomEvent', function() {
    alert('it works');
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks man, triggering the event on `$(document)` worked perfectly.

Comment: @Abhik good to hear! You can also trigger events on a element and then you have to listen on that element. But to start with it's simpler just to trigger and listen on `$(document)` happy coding!